# How can we add Edit Button to delete for Individaul cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface, builder

I added the edit button in the navigationbar. it works well and delete the cell. But , now i want to add the edit button to individaual cells to delete that cell only . what i mean that , if i have 5 cells enable in my tableview , i will add 5 edit buttons to them individaually.

Can u please anyone help me.

Thanks,

Chakradhar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    UIButton *btn=[UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.tag = 194;
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(290, 15, 25, 25)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(editTable:) 
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];      
}

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

NSString *cellValue = [myArrayNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
   return cell; }

-(void) editTable:(id) sender {

UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell]; }
```

Try this code and reply me ......

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a custom cell with a button for the table view and have the button perform the desired action upon click events